How do I mock a class that takes in T class with constructor parameters but without property?
Given that I have a class of:
public sealed class MySpecification : Specification<MyDomainObject>
{
    // This is all it really is, just a class with constructor that takes in parameters
    // No properties
    public MySpecification(int id)
    {
        Query.Where(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}

In my handler class where it takes care of the logic:
public async Task<MyDomainDto> Handle(MyHandler request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var spec = new MySpecification(request.myId);
    var myDomainEntity = await _myRepository.SingleOrDefaultAsync(spec, cancellationToken);

    // bunch of other logics, yada yada
}

I would like to do unit test on the handler. Right now I'm stuck on mocking the repository, this is what I have now:
public class MyHandlerTests
{
    private readonly IRepository<MyDomainObject> _myRepositoryMock;

    public MyHandlerTests()
    {
        _myRepositoryMock = Substitute.For<IRepository<MyDomainObject>>();
        _myRepositoryMock
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(Arg.Is<MySpecification>(x => x....??? ), Arg.Any<CancellationToken>())
            .Returns(myObject);
    }
}

How do I tell the _myRepositoryMock that if a parameter of type MySpecification is received with parameter of 1234, return myObject.
I've tried with Arg.Is<T>() but this only works if T have property. My T does not have any properties.

how do you think this is going to be made possible if MySpecification has no state to check against, i..e the 1234 is not saved anywhere, just used to construct the object

depends on how you provide the repo into your class.

@tinmanjk I don't know if it's even possible, that's why I asked. There might be some tricks that I'm not aware of :)

Won't you know if MySpecification has a property or not? x in your example will be the instance of the MySpecification object so you can just call any properties on there.
